# Simplified way to find duplicates in list of objects in vb.net and merge them

Tags: vb.net

I have an API that accepts a list of objects(Object contains ProductID and Quantity). I want to determine whether there are duplicate product ID on the passed list. If duplicates are found, I'll merge them by adding the Quantity of duplicate product ID. To do this, I created my own algorithm that loops the list one-by-one then store it to another list (the verified one). The code goes like this.

```
For Each passedVoucher As VoucherInfo In VouchersToRelease

     indexofduplicate = 0
     sumQuantity = 0
     hasDuplicate = False

     If VerifiedReleasedVouchers.Count() > 0 Then

         'for loop that checks if productID exists in the VerifiedReleasedVouchers
          For Each finalList As VoucherInfo In VerifiedReleasedVouchers

            If passedVoucher.ProductID = finalList.ProductID Then
                 indexofduplicate = VerifiedReleasedVouchers.IndexOf(finalList)

                 'if true, adds the Quantity of duplicate to the existing quantity at the VerifiedReleasedVouchers 
                 sumQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(VerifiedReleasedVouchers(indexofduplicate).Quantity) + Convert.ToInt32(passedVoucher.Quantity)

                 VerifiedReleasedVouchers(indexofduplicate).Quantity = sumQuantity.ToString

                 hasDuplicate = True
                 Exit For
            End If
         Next
      End If

      'adds the voucher to verified released voucher if no duplicate was found
      If hasDuplicate = False Then
         VerifiedReleasedVouchers.Add(passedVoucher)
      End If

 Next
```

So what I did is, I ForEach looped the passed list. Inside the loop, I compared the current object from the passedList into every object in the verifiedList(w/c is empty by default) to determine whether their are duplicate product ID. If no duplicate was found, i'll just add the current object to the verifiedList. If duplicate was found, ill just update the object from the verified list with the same ProductID by storing the sum of the Quantity of both objects.

The code above works perfectly as intended but the thing is, it performs a lot of tasks. Is there any way to simplify what I did above?

P.S. List.Distinct() is not a solution for this

Comment: If you want unique items numbers with quantities, my first thought is: try using a dictionary, that should perfectly fit for your needs.

Comment: You could also use Linq: Use `GroupBy` id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Linq to easily achieve what you want. First you must `GroupBy` ProductID and then `Select` all the groups with a sum of the quantity. Finally, we get a list:

```
Dim VerifiedReleasedVouchers As List(Of VoucherInfo) = VouchersToRelease.GroupBy(Function(x) x.ProductID).[Select](Function(y) New VoucherInfo() With {
.ProductID = y.Key,
.Quantity = y.Sum(Function(z) z.Quantity),
.Denom = y.First().Denom
}).ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks buddy it worked for me. But I have one problem. I have another field in my VoucherInfo named `Denom` (I have ProductID, Denom, and Quantity). How could I retain the original denom of my passed list?

Comment: Well, it depends. Is Denom always the same for the same productid?

Comment: Yeah it is. The only thing i modify during merge is the quantity

Comment: Then you could just add `,
    .Denom = y.First().Denom` to the `Select` part, after `.Quantity = y.Sum(Function(z) z.Quantity),` I've edited my answer